Get multiple values from checkbox with jquery
I have a website created with wordpress and elementor.
In my product page there is a product configurator and, when a user make a selection, this script print the selected value into a div:
Each of this step configuration have a unique choice.
Now, I need to take values from a multiselection of checkboxes, can anyone help me in editing the script?


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="color-group_266b5f37b0a48c"]').on("change", function() {
    var screen = $('input[name = "color-group_266b5f37b0a48c"]:checked').val();
    jQuery("#screen").html(screen);
  })
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="screen" style="text-align: right;font-weight:500;">

<div class="wcpa_field wcpa_group_field wcpa_fl_col-4 wcpa_disp_squircle wcpa_selection_tick">
<div class="wcpa_color"><label>
    <div class="wcpa_color_wrap " style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
        <input name="color-group_666e2a1e0c4c07[0]" type="checkbox" value="Pantone 319c">
        <div class="wcpa_color_bg" style="background-color: rgb(93, 192, 200);"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="wcpa_color_label"><span>Pantone 319c</span></p></label>
</div>
<div class="wcpa_color"><label>
    <div class="wcpa_color_wrap " style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
        <input name="color-group_666e2a1e0c4c07[1]" type="checkbox" value="Pantone 299c">
        <div class="wcpa_color_bg" style="background-color: rgb(14, 163, 222);"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="wcpa_color_label"><span>Pantone 299c</span></p></label>
</div>
<div class="wcpa_color"><label>
    <div class="wcpa_color_wrap " style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
        <input name="color-group_666e2a1e0c4c07[2]" type="checkbox" value="Pantone 274c">
        <div class="wcpa_color_bg" style="background-color: rgb(39, 38, 87);"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="wcpa_color_label"><span>Pantone 274c</span></p></label>
</div>
</div>




I made you a snippet. Please update it to make a [mcve] - there are no checkboxes in your code

If color-group_266b5f37b0a48c is a container then you need $('input[name = "color-group_266b5f37b0a48c"]').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() { return this.value}).get().join(',')

It's very difficult to reproduce the problem, because it is a product configurator plugin, this is the link of staging website
https://woocommerce-764650-4672759.cloudwaysapps.com/product/keychain-box
The multiple choice is in Screen Printing tab, and the values must be printed on right box.

Ok, i've make an example like configurator.

You need delegation and a better selector
Also your HTML was invalid and your group name was not what you posted


$(function() {
  const $checks = $('input[name^="color-group_666e2a1e0c4c07"]')
    .on("change", function() {
      const screen = $checks.filter(':checked')
        .map(function() {
          return this.value;
        })
        .get()
        .join(', ');
      $("#screen").text(screen);
    })
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="screen" style="text-align: right;font-weight:500;"></span>

<div class="wcpa_field wcpa_group_field wcpa_fl_col-4 wcpa_disp_squircle wcpa_selection_tick">
  <div class="wcpa_color">
    <div class="wcpa_color_wrap " style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
      <input name="color-group_666e2a1e0c4c07[0]" type="checkbox" value="Pantone 319c">
      <div class="wcpa_color_bg" style="background-color: rgb(93, 192, 200);">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="wcpa_color_label"><span>Pantone 319c</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="wcpa_color">
    <div class="wcpa_color_wrap " style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
      <input name="color-group_666e2a1e0c4c07[1]" type="checkbox" value="Pantone 299c">
      <div class="wcpa_color_bg" style="background-color: rgb(14, 163, 222);">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="wcpa_color_label"><span>Pantone 299c</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="wcpa_color">
    <div class="wcpa_color_wrap " style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
      <input name="color-group_666e2a1e0c4c07[2]" type="checkbox" value="Pantone 274c">
      <div class="wcpa_color_bg" style="background-color: rgb(39, 38, 87);">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="wcpa_color_label"><span>Pantone 274c</span></p>
  </div>
</div>




I shortened the code, I do not want to repeat the selector so I added a filter instead.
